# Why do we both "include" and "depends" on RcppArmadillo?

Tags: r, rcpp

To use `RcppArmadillo`, we're often instructed to have the following lines at the top:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
```

Why do we need both? Isn't the `#include` directive sufficient for us to have access to all functions defined inside the scope of `RcppArmadillo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different things at play:

1. The compiler needs the header `RcppArmadillo.h` in order to know about types from (Rcpp)Armadillo, Rcpp (as this one pulls in Rcpp.h as well) and therefore R.  I presume you know you need this.  But ...
2. How would R know to add the `-I...` flag required for this?  It wouldn't!

At a *package level* the `LinkingTo:` helps for the header case.  But in deeper sense sometimes we need headers *and* linking (ie RcppGSL) and in that case, the hook we have here via `Rcpp::depends` into Rcpp Attributes ensures we can do this.

So the `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` helps for `sourceCpp()` use. It is not needed in a package.  "Plugins" like this are discussed a little in the Rcpp Attributes vignette.